A horror short story where an almost-human woman gives birth to dozens of homunculi
I read this short story (or perhaps novelette) at least 20 years ago, probably more. I suppose it was in a collection, since I very rarely read magazines. I don't remember if I read it in French or in English.
I don't remember much. A "normal" man meets an alien who looks almost identical to a woman, and is very attractive. I don't remember if it is a SF horror story where he got to a different planet by spaceship, and was astonished that locals were so similar to humans. Or it is a Fantasy horror, where he traveled by ordinary ship to some unknown island (or maybe by land to some very  isolated place, but this seems unlikely) and only later realised the inhabitants were not "normal" humans.
IIRC, he takes her with him on his return trip. He has been repeatedly warned, either by his human travel companions, or by other alien "locals" not to have intercourse with her. But he did. I don't think he raped her. I even think she did a lot to persuade him against his reluctance to act against the warning he had received. But I am not positive about that.
Anyway after a short pregnancy she delivered dozens of homunculi who rapidly took over the spaceship (or regular ship - or possibly whatever land transport was used, but that does not look likely).
When he saw what had happened, I think he committed suicide.

EDIT
Emsley Wyatt suggested "The Lovers" by P. J. Farmer.
The character Hal Yarrow reasonably fits my memory.
What does fit is the mysterious way he met Jeanette, and his subsequent relationship to her is just as I remember.
So he did not commit suicide after she died giving birth, but the suicide may be a false memory.
Thanks to user14111 I have found the short (novella) version of this story. I am sure I did not read the novel version, and anyway it could only be worse.
It is not my story.
Something does not fit at all. Jeannette's offspring have to be put into an incubator. And the story continues many pages after her death when delivering the "larvae".
Maybe the man does not commit suicide. But my story ends rapidly after the birth on the dozens offsprings.
And I remember clearly that they are immediately active.
They might be "technically" larvae, like locusts larvae, not "imagos" because without sexual organs, smaller than adults but otherwise looking like them and immediately active.
Can anyone propose a totally different book ?

Did the story contain the actual word "homunculi"?

@Valorum I am not sure. I believe it did, but that might be a reconstruction. But I am positive that there were dozens of newborn, and that they looked like very small humans, and they were immediately active, not like human newborn.

"The Lovers" by  Philip José Farmer?

In the 31st century, the military starship Gabriel has arrived at the distant planet Ozagen. Its all-male crew represents the Haijac Union, where the "American" language is spoken. The Union is one of three powers dominating the planet Earth (the others are the Malay Federation and the Israeli Republics) since the Apocalyptic War, hundreds of years ago, decimated the Earth's population through bio-warfare. The Union is an extreme theocracy and religious tyranny in which everyone (including spouses) is expected to inform on one another for the slightest infractions.

I would note that the novel was expanded from a shorter work so perhaps that might account for you remembering a short story.

Unfortunately, you posted too late ! Even the "grace period" has expired just a few hours ago. I can only upvote your answer. The link user14111 posted was for a novella, the short version. The full novel would be even further from what I remember...

Hmmmm Even though it is only 148 pages long, the story in the link  user14111 posted is the novel, not the novella. So maybe you are right, maybe I did read the novella "The Lovers" but I need to have access to it to check. Indeed in the novel, Jeannette has many eggs, but the larvae needed an incubator. I have to read the novella to be sure. In that cas I'll accept your answer since novella and novel have the same title and you did not mention the length.

Well, no, user14111's link is to the 1952 version, which is the novella, even though the magazine calls it "a novel" The novel is from 1961 and being even longer would fit my memories even less.
